# .NET apps (api, mvc, blazor apps) unreachable on remote server - Connection Timeout Error

Tags: c#, linux, api, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I recently started developing .NET applications on a remote Linux server. Everything seems to be going fine until I wanted to test out the applications. For instance, I created a .NET web API on the server, however, when I tried to hit the endpoint `http://<serverip>:<port>`  from postman/chrome, I am getting a **connection timeout error**. I have changed the `applicationurl` from `localhost` to the `server ip` in the *launchSettings.json* file for me to access the api from outside the server and I am still unable to connect to the endpoint. I have also opened the port specified in the project on the server and I am still unable to access the endpoint. Please see the pictures attached below
[launchSettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amFNo.png)
[postmanerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U4dV.png)

The funny thing however is whenever I try to access the API endpoint from within the server, everything works perfectly. I have attached a picture below.
[serveroutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAXqi.png)

Please any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.